psql privilege warnings for schema public
I recently upgraded my local PostgreSQL to v17. Now when I create a database dump using pg_dump -c, importing that dump with psql on the server (running PostgreSQL 16) results in the following warnings:
WARNING:  no privileges could be revoked for "public"
WARNING:  no privileges were granted for "public"

I initially attributed the warnings to the fact that pg_dump now includes the command ALTER SCHEMA public OWNER TO snafu; (snafu being the local PostgreSQL superuser), and the schema public is owned by a different user on the server.
But when I add the --no-owner parameter to pg_dump (to suppress the commands changing ownership), the warnings still appear. Why is that? I used PostgreSQL 14 on my local client and PostgreSQL 16 on the server before, and the issue never occurred then.
Comparing the pg_dump output (v14 vs v17, without --no-owner), the only difference I found – apart from the ALTER SCHEMA command quoted above – are the ALTER commands for sequences:
CREATE SEQUENCE public.django_migrations_id_seq ... ;
# v14
ALTER TABLE public.django_migrations_id_seq OWNER TO django_db_user;
# v17
ALTER SEQUENCE public.django_migrations_id_seq OWNER TO django_db_user;

I checked the permissions for django_db_user and found that she had only permissions for tables, not sequences – but the CREATE SEQUENCE commands were executed without warnings. So the question remains why the ALTER TABLE statements (v14) do not trigger the warnings while the ALTER SEQUENCE statements (v17) do.
I can transfer ownership for the public schema to django_db_user to solve the problem temporarily, but the ALTER SCHEMA statement quoted above would always create an error.
